# /dev/sda1 not Accessible in Ophcrack

Tags: windows-7, linux, mount, ntfs

I have problems using the Ophcrack Live distribution on a PC with Windows 7. I can not in any way to see the C: drive.

I've tried everything, from entering as SU, I did `mount`, `mount force`, `mknode`, and more, but still nothing. If I do command `fdisk -l`, out the following:

```
    Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System

**/dev/sda1 * 1 29,294,496 xxxxx 7 HPFS / NTFS**

/dev/sda2 * xxxxx yyyyyy 29,294,496 7 HPFS / NTFS
```

I can see that `/dev/sda2` is correctly mounted to `/mnt`, but `/dev/sda1` can not be mounted in any way, why?

The problem may be that I'm not an administrator of the machine and the disk is somehow "protected" and not accessible?

**PS:** When accessing from Windows, I can see the C: drive, but *not*, for example, the folder `C:\Windows\System32\Config`.

Comment: Open a terminal and issue `mount | grep sda`. That will tell you (by listing all current mounts for `/dev/sda*` if it's mounted somewhere other than `/mnt`, which is possible. If not, try mounting it manually: (as root) `mkdir /mnt/sda1; mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1`

Comment: What you aren't seeing is a *mount* (the C partition's filesystem's contents being added to your fs tree - from your post you seem to be expecting it in /mnt/sda1), not the partition itself (the device node /dev/sda1).

Comment: Are you getting error messages when you issue any of those commands?

Comment: NO, nothing! :-(

if i try:

mkdir /mnt/sda1

and after

mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1

the result is: INVALID ARGUMENT

i've tryed also:

mount | grep sda

/dev/sda2 on /media/sda2 type fuseblk(rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blocksize=4096)

please help me!!!